# In SQL Server, what happens when a constraint is added to a table with data in it?

Tags: sql-server

Q&A for SQL Server migrated here from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168206/does-any-kind-of-constraint-in-a-database-have-a-unique-constraint-name).

What happens if a "NOT NULL" constraint is added to a table to a column that already has NULL values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question:

> What happens if a "NOT NULL" constraint is added to a table to a
>   column that already has NULL values?

A simple example in SQL Server is a constraint to disallow NULLs.

Create a table and insert two rows, one not null and one null.

```
USE tempdb

CREATE TABLE dbo.OneNull (c1 INT)

INSERT dbo.OneNull ( c1 )
    VALUES  (0), (NULL)
```

The `ALTER TABLE` syntax can direct what happens when you create the constraint. Using `WITH NOCHECK` will tell the engine (vroom vroom) not to check the column contents, but just to add the constraint for future rows.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.OneNull WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_checkone CHECK (c1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Adding this constraint runs successfully, but it means that the constraint is untrusted, and you lose certain query optimizations. For instance, if this were a Foreign Key, you would lose join elimination. For a column constraint, the optimizer can skip doing any work period if constraint information tells it that a search will yield no results.

But now this insert fails:

```
INSERT dbo.OneNull ( c1 )
    VALUES  (NULL)
```

You can also direct the engine (beep beep) to check the column values while adding the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.OneNull WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_checkonechecktwo CHECK (c1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Adding this constraint will fail.

If you add one with no formal direction (at least for column check constraints), the engine (screeeeech) will throw an error.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.OneNull ADD CONSTRAINT ck_checkornocheck CHECK (c1 IS NOT NULL)
```

An example of the type of optimization you can get with a **trusted** constraint is like so:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.OneNull WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_checkonechecktwo CHECK (c1 <= 1) 

INSERT dbo.OneNull ( c1 )
    VALUES  (1)

SELECT *
FROM dbo.OneNull AS onu
WHERE onu.c1 > 2
AND 1 = 1 --this is added to prevent a trivial plan
```

Rather than look for values at all, the engine (honk honk) knows that such a value can't exist because of the trusted constraint. Rather than put together a 'real' query plan and read any data, the optimizer short circuits and uses a Constant Scan operator to return NADA!

[image: Nuts]